# Java read text file valid count

Tags: java

im making a java file that can read a text file of football results some of which are invalid. The text file looks like this :

```
Chelsea : Manchester City : 2 : 1
Manchester United : Stoke City : 5 : 0
West Ham United : Middlesbrough : 2 : 2
Aston Villa:Fulham:4:1
Hull : :2:5
Arsenal Liverpool :2:2
```

The code must print out how many valid Array lines there are like the top 3 and also how many are invalid like the bottom 3... This is what I have so far:

```
public void showResults(){

        String separator = ":";
        File inputfile = new File ("valid.txt");

        String[] StrArray;
        String aLine = "";

        System.out.println ("Home "+"\tHome points" +  "\t Away " + "\t Away points  \n____________________________________________" );

        try {
            Scanner filescan = new Scanner(inputfile);
            while (filescan.hasNext()){
                aLine = filescan.nextLine();
                StrArray = aLine.split(separator);


                if (StrArray.length == 4){
                    System.out.println (StrArray[0] +"\t" + StrArray [2]  +  StrArray[1] + "\t" + StrArray[3]);
                }

            }

            filescan.close();
```

Any help would be welcomed i'm struggling a bit here, thanks in advance

Comment: Create two arrays outside your while loop. One for valid entries, the other for invalid entries. Modify your if into an if else and push valid (4 items per line) into valid array, anything else into invalid array. You can then loop your arrays to output your results.

Answer (score 0):

Call `split(":")` on every line. If the resulting array contains an empty string then it's invalid.

And by empty I mean `""` or `" "`. Anything with no characters in it.

Answer (score 0):

this mean this

```
String separator = ":";
    File inputfile = new File ("input.txt");

    String[] StrArray;
    String aLine = "";

    System.out.println ("Home "+"\tHome points" +  "\t Away " + "\t Away points  \n____________________________________________" );

    try {
        Scanner filescan = new Scanner(inputfile);
        while (filescan.hasNext()){
            aLine = filescan.nextLine();
            StrArray = aLine.split(separator);


            if (StrArray.length == 4 && !StrArray[0].isEmpty()
                    && !StrArray[1].isEmpty() && !StrArray[2].isEmpty()
                    && !StrArray[3].isEmpty())
            {
                System.out.println (StrArray[0] +"\t" + StrArray [2]  +  StrArray[1] + "\t" + StrArray[3]);
            }

        }

        filescan.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```